# How to communicate (network) with Docker at DigitalOcean?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

I'm trying to use [Docker - Build, Ship, and Run Any App, Anywhere](https://www.docker.com/) with [Simple Cloud Infrastructure for Developers | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), using following container: [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/nagev/tor/), [np1/docker-tor-clientonly](https://github.com/np1/docker-tor-clientonly).

Per author's instructions, I was able to run container:

```
mbp:~ alexus$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
bdcdabe8ab1d        nagev/tor           "/bin/sh -c '/usr/loc"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes       127.0.1.1:9150->9150/tcp   tor_instance
mbp:~ alexus$
```

What IP address should I use to set proxy inside of my browser?

Comment: The close vote is probably because this question has nothing to do with programming, and as such isn't really suited to StackOverflow.  Consider [superuser](http://superuser.com/), which is for general computer questions
.

Comment: @larsks fair comment, nevertheless `docker` tag exists here as well and it's used a lot more then at superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install docker with toolbox, here is the fix:

```
# run the container with all IPs, do not limit to 127.0.1.1
$ docker run -d --name tor_instance -p 9150:9150 nagev/tor

# find out the docker IP
$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100

# test the IP and port is available.
telnet 192.168.99.100 9150
Trying 192.168.99.100...
Connected to 192.168.99.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

Then you should be fine to set the sockets now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually that seems to be working in my local environment as well, however with digitalocean I'm unable to connect, I'm getting `Connection refused`.

Comment: Did you open the firewall to access that port in digitalocean?

Comment: No, that I guess, is the missing part in my puzzle) Where and/or how do I do that?

Comment: I have no account in digitalocean, so you have to figure it out by yourself.

Comment: My issue was that per developer's instructions `-p 127.0.1.1:9150:9150` was used, and that prevented me to connecting to it remotely. I use `docker-machine ip droplet` instead of `127.0.0.1` and it works!)

Comment: Nice to get feedback  that the problem is fixed.